# How to correctly handle EF concurrency errors?

Tags: c#, concurrency, entity-framework-6

I have found a lot of topics about concurrency errors, but seems that they all are about keeping database or client side values, but I need some sort of a hybrid solution - reloading initial value from database and retrying to change it (not just replacing store value with client side value).

**problem description**

Let's say I have database with 3 tables *Users*, *Orders* and *OrderSummaries* (example for the sake of simplicity of the problem explanation)

Each user has his orders, but orders are summarized in *OrderSummaries* table. When new *Order* is created, new record is added to *Orders* table and a summary record is Updated in *OrderSummaries* table

```
    //db -> DbContext instance
    var OrderSummariesRecord = db.OrderSummaries.FirstOrDefault(..filter expresion..);
    OrderSummariesRecord.Value += NewOrderRecord.Value;
    db.Entry(OrderSummariesRecord).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
```

So when 2 or more users are simultaneously adding new *Order* record, there could be concurrency error on updating *OrderSummaries* table

When concurrency error occurs I don't want to keep store or client value (which I find is the most proposed solution for this error), but I want to repeat the above OrderSummariesRecord assignment, but using current OrderSummariesRecord values from the database.

**my idea was to wrap this code in a loop, like this:**

```
Boolean saved = false;
while (!saved)
{
    try
    {
        var OrderSummariesRecord = db.OrderSummaries.FirstOrDefault(..filter expresion..);

        //would this be enough to make sure, that in the next iterations 
        //(after some concurrency errors has happened) the newest values from the
        //database are acquired?
        db.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, OrderSummariesRecord);

        OrderSummariesRecord.Value += NewOrderRecord.Value;
        db.Entry(OrderSummariesRecord).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        saved=true;
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        //some logging here
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        //Don't repeat - there's some other error
        saved=true;
    }
}
```

Currently I can not validate if this approach is (not) working... maybe some EF gurus from SO can take a look and validate that this should work or suggest a better/correct approach for handling concurrency in this type of scenario?

Comment: Just use a transaction. They are made for this use case. Under SERIALIZABLE you are guaranteed zero race conditions.

Comment: @usr thanks for the info. Do you have some good link with info how to use this with Entity Framework? Or maybe You could briefly explain it yourself as an answer to this post?